# Using SuperCsv with multiple variable columns

Tags: csv, supercsv

I was looking at this example from the Super CSV [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading_variable_cols.html) which shows that dateofbirth is optional column. What happens if i have more than one optional columns? How will the code change than?

```
 private static void readVariableColumnsWithCsvListReader() throws Exception {

        final CellProcessor[] allProcessors = new CellProcessor[] { new UniqueHashCode(), // customerNo (must be unique)
                new NotNull(), // firstName
                new NotNull(), // lastName
                new ParseDate("dd/MM/yyyy") }; // birthDate

        final CellProcessor[] noBirthDateProcessors = new CellProcessor[] { allProcessors[0], // customerNo
                allProcessors[1], // firstName
                allProcessors[2] }; // lastName

        ICsvListReader listReader = null;
        try {
                listReader = new CsvListReader(new FileReader(VARIABLE_CSV_FILENAME), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

                listReader.getHeader(true); // skip the header (can't be used with CsvListReader)

                while( (listReader.read()) != null ) {

                        // use different processors depending on the number of columns
                        final CellProcessor[] processors;
                        if( listReader.length() == noBirthDateProcessors.length ) {
                                processors = noBirthDateProcessors;
                        } else {
                                processors = allProcessors;
                        }

                        final List<Object> customerList = listReader.executeProcessors(processors);
                        System.out.println(String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, columns=%s, customerList=%s",
                                listReader.getLineNumber(), listReader.getRowNumber(), customerList.size(), customerList));
                }

        }
        finally {
                if( listReader != null ) {
                        listReader.close();
                }
        }
}
```

Also what if the optional columns are not at the end but in center or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the real issue here is that to apply the correct cell processors, you need to know what data is in each column. With a valid CSV file (same no. of columns on each line) that's not a problem, but if you're dealing with a variable column CSV file it's tricky.

If, like the example, only 1 column is optional then you just need to count the number of columns read and use the appropriate array of cell processors. It doesn't matter *where* that optional column is, because it's still predictable.

If, however, more than 1 column is optional you're in trouble. For example, if `middleName` and `city` are optional in the following CSV file:

```
firstName,middleName,lastName,city
Philip,Fry,New York
```

That can be read as:

```
firstName="Philip", middleName="Fry", lastName="New York", city=null
```

or

```
firstName="Philip", middleName=null, lastName="Fry", city="New York"
```

It's no longer predictable. You may be able to inspect the data in the column to determine what that column should represent (e.g. a date has `/`'s), but that's not very robust, and even then you may even have to read a few lines in order to figure it out.